# Determining Electricity Usage by Machine / Time Series Analysis?

Tags: time-series, arima

We are trying to identify the electricity needs of individual machines (efficiency) at our manufacturing facility in order to know the electricity-per-unit produced.

Over a series of shifts, we know:
1/ the electricity usage of clusters of machines - Draw(total), and
2/ the units produced by each individual machine - Production

[image]

**Bold is known**, *Italics are unknown*

Is there a type of analysis that I should be searching for?
I have started looking at Multivariate Time Series Analysis and ARIMA, but don't know what next steps to take.

Thank you!

Comment: This is an example of an *unidentifiable* model.  For every solution $(\text{draw}_i,\text{efficiency}_i)$ (where $i$ indicates the machine) there will be infinitely many other solutions of the form $(\text{draw}_i/\lambda_i,\text{efficiency}_i\lambda_i)$ where $0\lt\lambda_i\le 1$ (and possibly other solutions, as well). The first thing, then, is to refine your model into something that allows definite estimates to be made.

Comment: Look up Electric Load Disaggregation, this is a rather well studied problem

Comment: Thanks @Jonnor, I think this is the right direction to look in!